# I face sourceTree error - "Your repository isn't properly configured"

Tags: git, gitlab, atlassian-sourcetree

in my ventura-mac, sourcetree continuously show Your "repository isn't properly configured" and
"A remote repository's URL needs to match what's supported by your accounts. Please choose an option to resolve."

I have tried to change account swap like https -> ssh and ssh -> https
but it was same

anyone know solution of this error

- I have used gitlab CE account

change account protocol (https -> ssh) and (ssh -> https)

Answer (score 0):

This [thread mentions](https://ebookbrain.net/bitbucket-cloud-teams/):

> If your SSH settings are incorrect, you may get the following error.
>
> ```
> Repository not configured correctly
> A remote repository's URL needs to match what's supported by your accounts.
> ```

repair

> ```
> When I view my account, it has an exclamation mark.
> ```

Consider whether to use HTTPS or SSH, and reconfigure the communication settings.
For SSH, it is necessary to set the SSH key.

I would add, for HTTPS, you need to use a [PAT as a password](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html)